# SQL Server extract time from date and compare it

Tags: sql-server-2008, time, compare

My question is how to extract the time from a `datetime` field and compare it with another time extracted from `GetDate()` function?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE(), 101)` will get you the `Time` from `GETDATE()`.  You'd need to store it in a variable in order for you to use in your comparison.  Not elegant, but it works.

```
DECLARE @Time1 AS TIME(3)
DECLARE @Time2 AS TIME(3)
SELECT @Time1 = CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE(), 101)

SELECT @Time1;

SELECT @Time2 = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, GETDATE()), 101);

SELECT @Time2;

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Time1, @Time2)
```

Comment: And I get this error : Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.

Comment: @Jordan Borisov - then either you're mistaken about your server version (`time` didn't exist before the 2008 version), or the database you're working in is set to a lower compatibility level.

Comment: No. The version is 2008 and the database is fine wih the compatibilities levels.

Comment: @JordanBorisov: works just fine for me - on SQL Server 2008 R2 (but `TIME` was introduced in the 2008 version for sure)